# f:selectItems can't get value after reload

Tags: jsf, richfaces

I have a problem with the following code:

```
<rich:select value="#{MyBean.selectedItems}" id="mss"  defaultLabel="select" >
    <f:selectItems value="#{MyBean.availableItemList()}var="selectedItem" />
    <f:validator validatorId="util.MyValidator"/>
</rich:select>
```

It works good when i first time load the page but when i navigate back from the next page it fails and cant get the values again the list seems to be empty. The availableItemList() Method is the following:

```
public List<String> availableItemList()
            throws NoSuchMethodException, IllegalAccessException{
        try {

return  ( (ConcurrentHashMap<String,MyData>)MyDataHandler.getFileData()).get(network).getItemList();

        } catch(NullPointerException e) {
            List<String> tmp = new ArrayList<String>();
            tmp.add("asd");
            return tmp;
        }
```

As i said it works good when i first load the page(it returns items related to the selected network from the datahandler) but after navigating  the try part seems to fail and it throws the exception message in the catch. If i just press the back button of the browser from an other page i can see the items and select one but when i press the commit button it fails and the catch parts comes again with the error message.

I will try to make it clear but i can't copy the whole code because of company secrets and blabla. So the Datahandler gains the data from an XML file(contains the network data) and stores it in a

```
 protected static ConcurrentHashMap<String,?> fileData
```

It has getter and setter too:

```
 public static ConcurrentHashMap<String, ?> getFileData() {
        return NetworkDataHandler.fileData;
    }
```

The network data looks like this:

```
private String networkName;
private List<String> mssList;
```

with getter and setters.

Comment: Can you please share the exception and tell that what is the scope of `MyBean` class

Comment: It's sessionscoped. the part in the catch "asd" is being displayed in the dropdown list after navigating back so it seems to be a nullpointer exception

Comment: Have you provide getter and setters of `availableItemList` in `MonitorBean`. Also pleae tell the scope of `MonitorBean`

Comment: Also while catching exception put `e.printStackTrace()` in catch block to get the detailed exception and then print the exception here

Comment: availableItemList is just a method, it is the second part of the code i copied which gets the data from an other class(MyDataHandler).

Comment: http://codeviewer.org/view/code:33d5 Here is the exception

Comment: Maybe the problem that it is a method so there is no getter and setter so it can't restore it because of that?

Comment: ok So after seeing your stacktrace I found that the problem in your code is this line `(ConcurrentHashMap<String,MyData>)MyDataHandler.getFileData()).get(network).getItemList();` Am I right? Is this line 192 of `MonitorBean.java`?

Comment: Yes the problem is with that row. It works fine when i first time load the page but after i navigate back from the next page it seems to fail and throws that nullpoint exception.

Comment: oh I just see.Your method `List<String> availableMSSList()` has return type List and you returning a map? What is this man?

Comment: No, the getItemList method at the end returns a List of Strings based on the network(get(network)) from that map, The map is static thats why i can access it like that.

Comment: then why are you casting it in `(ConcurrentHashMap<String,MyData>)`

Comment: It should give you compile time error even if you are using any IDE then It must showed you red error line below the code.I am unable to understand that How it is working first time.

Comment: Where is your variable `network` comming from?

Comment: Anyway It is not my part they just dropped me to this project and i have to work whit this :/ I also find this part weird

Comment: network is also in the same bean with the method

Comment: But as i said there is no error in the Code everything works fine when i first time load the page the List works fine i can select one and it also can save and submit. But after i navigate back somehow the whole stuff fails and drops that exception

Comment: I updated the code above and provided a bit more information maybe it helps.